# Drop from Kendo TreeView to div in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I'm trying to drag and drop from a Kendo TreeView to a div (in AngularJS).

[This plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1wbjBNAZxLTZxTL9kwSV?p=preview) doesn't work, as I'm not telling the TreeView that the dropHere div is a drop target.

In jQuery I would use,

```
$("#dropHere ").kendoDropTarget();
```

but what is the Angular way?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter "e" of drop function have a property named valid, use this to decide if you can drop your item.
On div, append a repeat structure, pointing to a array.
if is drop.valid, push the item to the array.
The angularjs will make the rest.

Comment: I don't want to push the item into an array, just append it to the div in the top/left coordinates